# How to convert the array elements to lowercase using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have an array field in my elasticsearch document.

```
Array = ["German", "Spanish" , "English"]
```

I want to convert it to  below format

```
Array = ["greman", "spanish", "english" ]
```

How can I convert the array content to lowercase while reindexing using Logstash?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in Logstash, you can leverage the [`mutate / lowercase` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-lowercase):

```
filter {
   ...

   mutate {
        lowercase => [ "Array" ]
   }

   ...
}
```

You could also do this using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/lowercase-processor.html) in Elasticsearch:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/lowercase-pipeline
{
  "description": "Bla bla",
  "processors": [
    {
      "lowercase": {
        "field": "Array"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And then in your Logstash configuration, make sure to parameterize your `elasticsearch` output to use that pipeline

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    pipeline => "lowercase-pipeline"
    ...
  }
}
```